# Show Calendar RSS sorted by Start Date

Tags: rss

I have a user who is trying to use the RSS feed on a Calendar List to import into another application and wants the feed to render by "Start Date" rather than by "Created Date" how can this be accomplished? I was thinking of the Object Model or using the Lists web service to render the data.

Bismarck